# Wordpress working with angular bindings

Tags: javascript, wordpress, angularjs, binding, ng-bind

Hi I have been working on this web application and I put this code http://jsbin.com/quponase/3/edit into a wordpress page and it stopped working. I have been trying to not use the double curly braces and instead use ng-bind since I read wordpress has a problem with double curly braces here is that code as well http://jsbin.com/nuqir/1/edit. I get some kind of Lexer error but I can not find anywhere what means. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I figured out what was wrong. The 2 jsbins look the same but Wordpress was changing some of the quotation marks. Instead of putting my javascript in the "text" area of the wysiwyg part of Wordpress I put in as a template and it worked.